# html table error in spacing and margin

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table in html like given in the link [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2gm3.png)

[image]

I have tried but didnt work.
MY CODE

```css
.td1 {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.td2 {
 background-color: red;
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
}

.td3 {
 background-color: green;
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 200px;
}

.td4 {
 background-color: blue;
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
}

.td5 {
 margin: 5px;
 background-color: yellow;
 border: 2px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
}

.table {
    border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 25px 5px;
 margin: 5px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="table">
    <tr><td colspan="3" class="td1" align="center"> <b>DIV1</b>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="td2" align="center" rowspan="3"><b>DIV2</b></td>
    <td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="td3" align="center" rowspan="2"><b>DIV3</b></td>
    <td></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="td4" align="center"><b>DIV4</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3" class="td5" align="center"><b>DIV5</b>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did nothing work? Or just a couple of things? Try being more specific.

Comment: Kenny, go to learn how to use copy and paste... And: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265210/asking-for-a-fiddle-in-comments

Comment: Don't find it good method the way you try to achieve this.

Comment: You should try to use more than one table to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in your css

```
.table tr{
 height:100px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uwokm8oq/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the "rowspan"-attribute, you already have a div inside your tds.

Give the 2nd tr a height in the css and to the three divs in the tds inside, add a height-attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Have noticed that you have:

```
 border-spacing: 25px 5px;
```

Change it to:

```
 border-spacing: 5px 5px;
```

This spacing is for the distance between the borders of the cells.
Here you can read more about [border-spacing](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp)!